# Python multiprocessing on same method that deals with data

Tags: python, django, multithreading, multiprocess

I have a Django application where I am trying to manage the data for one of my models, since the number of its table rows in the database has gotten quite unruly.

I have a model staticmethod that gets all the 'Vehicle' objects in my database, goes through them, check if their image url is still active, and if not deletes it.

There are 1.2 million records (and some records have more than one image to check) so its going to take a pretty long time to go through all the records.

I know that you can use threading to run multiple processes, but I also know that for a method that deals with data, each thread has to be aware of the other thread. Is there a way that I can use multithreading to cut down the time it would take to go through a queryset and make those checks, e.g. If the first thread looks at queryset item 1, and 2, thread 2 will start looking at queryset item 3, and than thread 1 will skip to queryset item 4 if its done, and thread 2 hasn't finished with queryset item 3 ?

Method

```
@staticmethod
    def image_existence_check():
        import threading
        import requests
        from dealer.models import Dealer

        vehicles = Vehicle.objects.all()

        for index, veh in enumerate(vehicles):

            images = veh.images.all()

            if images.count() == 1:
                image = images[0]

                response = requests.get(image.image_url)

                if response.status_code == 200:
                    veh.has_image = True
                else:
                    veh.has_image = False
            elif images.count() > 1:
                has_image = True

                for img in images:
                    response = requests.get(img.image_url)

                    if response != 200:
                        has_image = False

                veh.has_image = has_image

            else:

                veh.has_image = False

            veh.save()
```

Comment: Do you have to accomplish this task with Django or even with Python? If you just need to clean up your database, there are other options.

Comment: Well if it was something like 'go through and delete all vehicles whose make is 'Toyota' or something along those lines, I would just do it with SQL, but since I need to check if the image exists via http requests, I can't think of any more efficient way to do it'.

Comment: Another question, should `veh.has_image` be true if `veh` has AT LEAST one image, or only if all the images in `veh.images` exist? Right now, they way you wrote it, if there are multiple images in the list, `veh.has_image` will be set to `False` if even one of the images doesn't exist (i.e. returns a status code other than 200). Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: That is correct, thats intended behavior.

Comment: Well ubadub, I managed to cut down the time for processing drastically by using multiprocessing, but if feels to good to be true. What are the trade offs too using multiprocessing, does it result in higher CPU usage ? How many processes can you use at one time ? I believe with threads its 1 for every CPU core processor you have, but I could be wrong. Is it the same with multiprocessing.

Comment: Use a threadpoolexecutor and then map enumerate.